# How to WriteAllText but restrict to overwrite the existing file?

Tags: vb.net

Jan 8. 2023:
The AppendAllText can append into existing file and can create a file if no file exist.
the WriteAllText can Write into new created file and overwrite the existing file.

I'm trying to find another alltext for what I want to happen.

What I want to do is to save my textboxcontent.text into txt file.
I want to save 3 different content that will be displayed into my textboxcontent.text
And I only have one button.

That one button will open savefiledialog but with the code I have, I can only do 2 things, Write and Append.

Now, This is what suppose to happen.

- *If I save the textcontent.text to an existing txt file, it will prompt message box "Do you want to overwrite this file?" And even if I click Yes, it will not allow to.
- I must be able to create new txt file since I was not able to overwrite the file.

The reason is because I don't want to delete or overwrite the existing file with important information saved in it.

I hope somebody can help me.

This is the code I have.

````
```Imports System.io
Private lastSaveFileName As String = String.Empty
Private Function GetSaveFileName3(ByVal suggestedName As String) As String
    Using sfd3 As New SaveFileDialog()
        sfd3.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) |*.txt"
        sfd3.FileName = suggestedName
        sfd3.OverwritePrompt = True


        If DialogResult.OK Then

        End If
        If sfd3.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            MessageBox.Show(
            Me, "Your activity is not saved! This file have records from your last session, you cannot overwrite this file. Please create new file to save new records.",
            "Save error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation
        )
        Else


        End If
        Return String.Empty
    End Using
    
End Function
Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    lastSaveFileName = GetSaveFileName3(lastSaveFileName)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastSaveFileName) Then
        File.AppendAllText(lastSaveFileName, TextContent.Text)
    End If




End Sub ' This code above includes IMPORTS.IO
````

Jan 9, 2023: Update

This is what I've done so far.

I tried to use the File.Exist but I don't know where to place it to make it run in the way I wanted.

Please see this code and help me fix it.
This code is running well in almost the way I want. I'm missing something.

```
Imports System.IO
Private lastSaveFileName As String = String.Empty

Private Sub SaveFile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveFile.Click
    If Not File.Exists(lastSaveFileName) Then
        lastSaveFileName = GetSaveFileName(lastSaveFileName)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastSaveFileName) Then
            File.WriteAllText(lastSaveFileName, txtdisplay1.Text)
        End If
    ElseIf File.Exists(lastSaveFileName) Then
        lastSaveFileName = GetSaveFileName2(lastSaveFileName)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastSaveFileName) Then
            File.WriteAllText(lastSaveFileName, txtdisplay1.Text)
        End If
    End If

    
End Sub

Private Function GetSaveFileName2(ByVal suggestedName As String) As String
    Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
        sfd.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) |*.txt"
        sfd.FileName = suggestedName
        sfd.OverwritePrompt = True

        If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            'If File.Exists(lastSaveFileName) Then
            MessageBox.Show(
       Me, "Your activity is not saved! This file have records from your last session, you cannot overwrite this file. Please create new file to save new records.",
       "Save error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation
   )   
        End If  
        Return String.Empty
    End Using
End Function

Private Function GetSaveFileName(ByVal suggestedName As String) As String
    Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
        sfd.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) |*.txt"
        sfd.FileName = suggestedName
        sfd.OverwritePrompt = True

        If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Return sfd.FileName
        End If
        Return String.Empty
    End Using
End Function
```

With this code, I was able to save the textdisplay to a txtfile but it's like, it's bypassing the Elseif function.

Sometimes, poeple forgot to avoid important files and accidentally deleted it. This is what I'm preventing to happen.

I let the overwriteprompt true to let it ask the user if they want to replace. It accidentally click the yes, this will show message "This file have records from your last session, Please create new file to save new records." means that even the user want to replace it, the program will not allow it. I don't want to remove that scenario.

(Scenario 1)
What happen in this code is this, when I click the button, savefiledialog pop up and giving me choice how I want to save the textdisplay.
I can create new file or replace existing file.
First, I choose to replace, and a messagebox shows and saying, I can't replace the file.
Then I create new file, it lets me save the txt display normally.

(scenario 2)
That's what I want. The code runs that way at first, but if you click the button again, and try to create new file first, the message box will show saying I can't replace the file. then when I choose to replace, no message box shows and the file was replace. I lost the file.

That's where I need help. I only want the Scenario 1.
Please try on your own I you don't get what I mean.

Comment: Please anyone, I need help with this.

Comment: It looks like you need to remove the lines `If DialogResult.OK Then` `End If`.

Comment: You write "And even if I click Yes, it will not allow to." - do you mean it gives you an error message? If it does then we need to know exactly what that error message is.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, right now, when I click the button with that code, it shows dialog, letting me to create or overwrite file. In some case, the user may forgot that the file is important and still overwrite it and that's what I want to stop. So, I let the overwritepromt to True and after clicking yes, it shows msgbox " Your data is not saved. This file has important record. Please create new file to save your data". And it rejects the overwrite. This is correct and this is what I need. But here's the problem,

Comment: @AndrewMorton the problem is, when I try now to create new txtfile, the same message box is showing and that's what I'm trying to fix. Because I want to be able to create new file and but not allowed to overwrite. With this, I can prevent losing files.

Comment: You can check if a file already exists with the [File.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists) method. So you could check if it's already there and ask the user to choose a different filename, if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I answer my question to add an update. I still not able to solve my problem. @AndrewMorton

Comment: I can't figure out from your logic when you append and when you create a new file.  You make things more confusing when you offer the end user the option to replace, but then secretly won't let them replace, or something like that.  If you don't have your decision tree correctly diagrammed, it's hard to get the programming right.

Comment: Yes, you somehow understand it. I don't want to secretly wont replace a file. I want to let them know that the request is did not go through and also to tell them to just create new. I still want to offer a option to replace for at least higher the chance of prevention of accidentally deleted/replaced a file.

Comment: So you never append a file, you always create new.

Comment: If it is important that the user doesn't lose the file completely, perhaps you could rename the old one before writing a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and this code works the way I want.

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    If File.Exists(saveFileDialog1.FileName) Then
        MessageBox.Show("A file with that name already exists. Please select a different file name or choose a different location to save the file.")
    Else
        File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Txtdisplay1.Text)
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answered by: schoemr

Comment: Related Post here with answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75087043/what-to-do-to-reject-a-replace-txt-file-request-and-offer-them-to-create-new-tx